# (Supposedly) Asynchronous queries wait for result

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous

My purpose is to query a remote database, querying a single (but different for each table) field in many (up to 5000) tables:

```
SELECT FOO FROM TABLEA WHERE ...
SELECT BAR FROM TABLEB WHERE ...
```

So far, the code used has been:

```
Public Class ValuesRepository
    Private connectionString As String
    Private BatchOdbcConnection As IDbConnection

    Public Sub New(connectionString As String)
        Me.connectionString = connectionString
        BatchOdbcConnection = New Odbc.OdbcConnection("DRIVER={AspenTech ODBC driver for Production Record Manager};" + connectionString)
    End Sub

    PublicFunction GetAllBatchValues(tagList As IEnumerable(Of BatchTag)) As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of Double?))
        Dim returnList As New List(Of IEnumerable(Of Double?))
        If tagList.Count = 0 Then Return returnList
        BatchOdbcConnection.Open()
        For Each batchTag In tagList
            Dim result As Double? = GetBatchList(batchTag.fieldName, batchTag.tableName)
            If result Is Nothing Then
                Continue For
            Else
                returnList.Add(result.Value)
            End If
        Next
        BatchOdbcConnection.Close()
        Return returnList
    End Function

    Private Function GetBatchList(fieldName As String, tableName As String) As IEnumerable(Of Double?)
        Const SQLQuery As String = "SELECT ""{0}"" FROM ""{1}"";"

        Dim query = String.Format(SQLQuery,
                                  fieldName,
                                  tableName)
        Dim queryResult = BatchOdbcConnection.Query(Of Double?)(query, commandType:=CommandType.Text)
        Return queryResult
    End Function
End Class
```

I have profiled the code, and up to 70% of the time is spend waiting in Dapper's `Query` method, which is rather inefficient.

I have been trying to improve this by making it all asynchronous, in order to start the next query before one is completed:

```
Public Class ValuesRepository
    Private connectionString As String

    Public Sub New(connectionString As String)
        Me.connectionString = connectionString
    End Sub

    Private Function GetOdbcConnection() As IDbConnection
        Return New Odbc.OdbcConnection("DRIVER={AspenTech ODBC driver for Production Record Manager};" + connectionString)
    End Function

    Public Function GetAllBatchValues(tagList As IEnumerable(Of BatchTag)) As IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of Double))
        Dim returnList As New List(Of IEnumerable(Of Double?))
        If tagList.Count = 0 Then Return returnList

        Dim tasks As New List(Of Task(Of IEnumerable(Of Double?)))

        For Each batchTag In tagList
            tasks.Add(GetBatchList(batchTag.fieldName, batchTag.tableName))
        Next

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray())

        For Each task In tasks
            Dim result = task.Result
            If result Is Nothing Then
                Continue For
            Else
                returnList.Add(result.Value)
            End If
        Next
        Return returnList
    End Function

    Private Async Function GetBatchList(fieldName As String, tableName As String) As Task(Of IEnumerable(Of Double?))
        Console.WriteLine("Begin " + fieldName + " -> " + tableName)
        Using conn = GetOdbcConnection()
            Const SQLQuery As String = "SELECT ""{0}"" FROM ""{1}"";"

            Dim query = String.Format(SQLQuery,
                                  fieldName,
                                  tableName)

            Dim queryResult = Await conn.QueryAsync(Of Double?)(query, commandType:=CommandType.Text)
            Console.WriteLine("End " + fieldName + " -> " + tableName)
            Return queryResult
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
```

I have been expected it to start all queries, and then wait for results, and therefore to read in the console something like:

```
Begin: Foo -> TableA
Begin: Bar -> TableB
...
End: Bar -> TableB
End: Foo-> TableA
```

Instead, the console reads:

```
Begin: Foo -> TableA
End: Foo-> TableA
Begin: Bar -> TableB
```

And it is quite clear from the cadencing that the application is actually waiting for the query to end after each call.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It does work when I use `Await Task.Delay` instead of `Await conn.QueryAsync`

Comment: I tought my comment was nonsense but seems like it wasn't. If it does work, then you got a new question "How come Await conn.QueryAsync block all active task?". Check if your version of the driver support Async calls.

Comment: That was the issue. I did not realize asynchronous ODBC needed to be implemented in the driver. It turns out it was not. Could you post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: I would be curious if creating threads to old fashion way would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace Await conn.QueryAsync with Await Task.Delay and see if that works. If it does work, then you got a new question "How come Await conn.QueryAsync block all active task?". Check if your version of the driver support Async calls. It's possible to have a method called QueryAsync but in the back, it call a driver that doesn't support Async.

Comment: It turns out AspenTech's Production Record Manager OBDC driver does not support asynchronous methods, hence the synchronous execution.